# Simple TCP server can't output to web browser

Tags: c, sockets, server

I wrote a simple TCP client and server program in C language.

It works fine among them but I have a doubt.

What if I wanted to access the TCP server from the web server?

I got the headers from web server and I can't `write()` back to the web browser. Should the response be in `HTTP` specifications compulsorily?

**I get the following error**:

[image]

**Server Code:**

```
// Server side C program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PORT 8080
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket; long valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("In socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("In bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("In listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
        printf("Hello message sent\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9



Hello message sent
```

What is the problem? Is browser also expecting `HTTP` type response from the server? As the server is sending plain text, web browser can't display the contents. Is this the reason for the error displayed in web browser?

Comment: Yes, when you talk to the browser you have to do it in a language it understands. It is the same with any protocol (FTP, SSH, ...)

Comment: Yes. Your response is not valid HTTP and thus Firefox rejects it, use a HTTP response skeleton snippet somewhere and work from there.

Comment: this may be handy: https://www.mocky.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the problem? Is browser also expecting HTTP type response from the server? As the server is sending plain text, web browser can't display the contents. Is this the reason for the error displayed in web browser?

**Yes**, the browser expects a HTTP response.

Here a simple HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 12

Hello world!
```

C Code snippet:

```
const char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello world!";
```

Parts explained:

`HTTP/1.1` specifies the HTTP protocol version.

`200 OK` is the so called **response status**. 200 means no error.

[List of HTTP status codes (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

`Content-Type` and `Content-Length` are http headers:

- `Content-Type` refers to the content type (who would've guessed?). `text/plain` means plaintext. (There is also `text/html`, `image/png` etc..)
- `Content-Length` total size of the response in bytes.

Comment: So after the HTTP headers, we have to give 2 newlines and then the content which we want to display. Am I right?

Comment: @ssh Yes, exactly.