# Curl doesn't send entire form-data in HTTP POST request

Tags: c, sockets, http, server, http-headers

**Edit:**

**Problem: 2** and **Problem: 3** solved by following @melpomene comment i.e., by using number of bytes read to print the buffer.

But still struck on **Problem: 1**.

---

I have written a TCP server-client program. Later out of curiosity, I want to know about HTTP server.

My previous question: [Simple TCP server can't output to web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49152320/7517228)

Now I'm just seeing what and how the data is transferred to the server by using `GET` and `POST`( `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` for now).

I'm following [How to cURL POST from the Command Line](http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/30/curl-post-request-command-line-syntax/) to send `POST` requests.

When I send `x-www-form-urlencoded` as:

```
curl -d "data=example1&data2=example2" localhost:8080
```

**Output on Server**:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data=example1&data2=example2
```

This is as expected.

---

**Problem: 1**

Now comes the problem. When I try to send `form-data`, the output is not expected.

When I send `form-data` as:

```
curl -X POST -F "name=user" -F "password=test" localhost:8080
```

**Output on server**:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 244
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------78b7f8917ad1992c
```

I'm getting the boundary but I'm not getting the next part like the data I'm sending.

**Problem: 2**

One more odd thing is when I try to send `x-www-form-urlencoded` after sending `form-data`.

When I send `x-www-form-urlencoded` after `form-data` as:

```
curl -d "data=example1&data2=example2" localhost:8080
```

**Output on server**:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data=example1&data2=example2------------78b7f8917ad1992c
```

Why am I getting `boundary` here?

**Problem: 3**

And also while sending `GET` as:

```
curl localhost:8080
```

**Output on server**:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*

ontent-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data=example1&data2=example2------------78b7f8917ad1992c
```

I'm getting `Content-Type` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` data along with `boundary`.

**What am I doing wrong?
Is something wrong with my code or with my understanding?**

**Server.c**:

```
// Server side C program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8080
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket; long valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: 12\n\nHello world!";

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("In socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );


    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("In bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("In listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
        printf("------------------Hello message sent-------------------\n");
        close(new_socket);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No error checking on `read()` call...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry for that. I have checked now. It is returning positive value.

Comment: I guess the `buffer` is printing previous values. Just move `char buffer[1024] = {0}` inside your `while(1)` loop and check it

Comment: You need to actually use `valread`. You can't just call `printf` `%s` on data you received from a socket (no `\0` terminator).

Comment: I have used Postman app to check your code. It works everything fine in it. The problem might be in sending headers in `curl` command.

Comment: @melpomene I thought the `read()` will automatically insert `\0` after reading. Your solution solves the last 2 problems but i'm still facing the 1st problem i.e., can't receive `form-data`.

Comment: @ssh Have you tried reading all of the data from the socket, not just the first chunk?

Comment: @melpomene I have also increased the buffer size to 3000. But still I can't get the result. As @SkrewEverything said, when I try on Postman.app, I can get the result. But I can't get while using `curl`.

Comment: The buffer size doesn't matter. You need to call `read` repeatedly until you reach the end of the data.

Comment: @melpomene I have tried to `read()` in `while(1)`. If the return value is less than `1`, the loop breaks. It works now. It prints everything in `form-data` but I have to press `ctrl+c` after the `curl` command. Is there any way to avoid pressing `ctrl+c` after `curl`

Comment: @melpomene I mean while using Postman.app, I can read entire thing in one go. Is it possible to mimic same behaviour while using `curl`?

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for your help. Got the solution from SkrewEverything answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem 1**

I have checked the request headers and found `Expect: 100-continue` header. This is the first time I have seen this header.

A simple search in Google shows this is causing the problem.

[Expect: 100-Continue' Issues and Risks](https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/articles/213492003--Expect-100-Continue-Issues-and-Risks) (I'm just gonna paste everything to avoid dead link)

> **How the Expect: 100-Continue Header Works**
>
> When Expect: 100-Continue is NOT present, HTTP follows approximately the following flow (from the
>   client's point of view):
>
> **1.** The request initiates a TCP connection to the server.
>
> **2.** When the connection to the server is established, the full request--which includes both the request headers and the request body--is transmitted to the server.
>
> **3.** The client waits for a response from the server
>   (comprised of response headers and a response body).
>
> **4.** If HTTP
>   keep-alives are supported, the request is optionally repeated from
>   step 2.
>
> When the client is using the Expect: 100-Continue feature, the
>   following events occur:
>
> **1.** The request initiates a TCP connection to the server.
>
> **2.** When the
>   connection to the server is established, the request--including the
>   headers, the Expect: 100-Continue header, without the request body--is
>   then transmitted to the server.
>
> **3.** The client then waits for a response
>   from the server. If the status code is a final status code, using the
>   prior steps above the client retries the request without Expect:
>   100-Continue header. If the status code is 100-Continue, the request
>   body is sent to the server.
>
> **4.** The client will then wait for a response
>   from the server (comprised of response headers and a response body).
>
> **5.** If HTTP keep-alives are supported, the request is optionally repeated
>   from step 2.
>
> **Why use Expect: 100-Continue?**
>
> API POST requests that
>   include the Expect: 100-Continue header save bandwidth between the
>   client and the server, because the server can reject the API request
>   before the request body is even transmitted. For API POST requests
>   with very large request bodies (such as file uploads), the server can,
>   for example, check for invalid authentication and reject the request
>   before the push body was sent, resulting in significant bandwidth
>   savings.
>
> **Without Expect: 100-Continue:**
>
> Without the Expect: 100-Continue
>   feature, the entire API request, including the (potentially large)
>   push body would have to be transmitted before the server could even
>   determine if the syntax or authentication is valid. However, since the
>   majority of our API requests have small POST bodies, the benefits of
>   separating the request header from the request body is negligible.
>
> **Problems when the request header and body are sent separately**
>
> Because
>   of the high volume of requests that Urban Airship handles, many levels
>   of complexity exist between our clients and the servers responsible
>   for responding to API requests. This is not an abnormal phenomenon for
>   most server configurations and strategies, but it does introduce a
>   risk of elevated request failures to any API POST requests using the
>   Expect: 100-Continue header. This is due to the fact that the request
>   header and the request body are sent separately from one another, and
>   must travel through the same connection throughout the entire API
>   server infrastructure.
>
> With the number of proxies, load-balancing servers, and back-end
>   request processing servers that are implemented, requests with the
>   Expect: 100-Continue header have an increased probability of becoming
>   separated from one another, and hence returning with an error.
>
> **What To Expect:**
>
> We've always attempted to support Expect: 100-Continue.
>   However, we have determined that our customers that use Expect:
>   100-Continue are receiving a sub-optimal quality of service due to
>   elevated request failures.
>
> Additionally, the majority of our API requests have small POST bodies,
>   and as a result the benefits of separating the request header from the
>   request body are negligible. These reasons have motivated us to
>   disable support for Expect: 100-Continue service-wide.
>
> **Our Recommendations:**
>
> We recommend against the use of Expect:
>   100-Continue. If you receive an HTTP Error 417 (Expectation failed),
>   retry the request without Expect: 100-Continue.

So, to prevent `Expect: 100-continue` header in `POST` `form-data`, include `-H 'Expect:'` in your `curl

```
curl -X POST -F "name=user" -F "password=test" localhost:8080 -H 'Expect:'
```

Now you can receive your entire data in one go(just like Postman) as you said in comments.

---

**Problem 2 & 3**

As @melpomene said in comments, `read()` doesn't put `\0` after reading. That's why you are seeing data from previous requests.

So, just use `valread` to iterate over string to print or just declare variable in your while loop as I said in the comments.

**Code**:

```
while(1)
    {
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char buffer[30000] = {0};  // This way you get new variable everytime. So, there is no need to iterate over the string using valread value.
        valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 30000);
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
        printf("------------------Hello message sent-------------------%lu\n", valread);
        close(new_socket);
    }
```

Comment: Mee too. I never saw that header. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: -H 'Expect:' --- holy cow, who would have guessed. Thanks for that.